# Infer method return type from match case

Tags: scala, templates

I have a long list of cases in a match as follows:

```
input match {
  case input: InputTypeA => handleTypeA(input)
  case input: InputTypeB => handleTypeB(input)
  case input: InputTypeC => handleTypeC(input)
  ...and so on
}
```

The handlers are defined as:

```
private def handleTypeA(input: InputTypeA): InputTypeA.Output = {...}
private def handleTypeB(input: InputTypeB): InputTypeB.Output = {...}
private def handleTypeC(input: InputTypeC): InputTypeC.Output = {...}
```

The InputTypes are defined as:

```
trait InputBaseType {}

trait OutputBaseType {}

class InputTypeA extends InputBaseType {
  class Output extends OutputBaseType {}
}

class InputTypeB extends InputBaseType {
  class Output extends OutputBaseType {}
}

class InputTypeC extends InputBaseType {
  class Output extends OutputBaseType {}
}
```

Is there a way that the definition of each handler can be cleaner? I feel like the `match` statement already extracts the type of Input, and handler return type can be inferred. Is this possible?

Comment: The handler would exist even if the match did not, the handler return type cannot be inferred from the match.

Comment: Is there a smarter way to do this? I feel like I am writing a lot of repetitive code.

Comment: I would maybe use a typeclass pattern to replace your individuals handler method and the match. Something like `trait Handler[T]`. Without more context it's hard to give an answer and it's out of the original question scope.

Comment: Not all repetition is bad. In real life applications it's not a rare case that relying on the type inference leads to bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The essential issue here seems to be that the code is performing dynamic binding by hand. It checks the type of `input` and uses this to decide which handler to invoke. Polymorphism can do all this for you. Each handler method should be moved to the appropriate `InputType` class (or you could use a Strategy), and then the case analysis is replaced by simply `input.handle`. I'm basing this on the code I see -- there may be other reasons why you're not doing it this way.